# Android BottomSheetBehavior, how to disable snap?

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottom-sheet

Standard android BottomSheetBehavior has tree state: hidden, collapsed and expanded.

I want to allow user to "leave" bottom sheet between collapsed and expanded. Now, with the default behavior, it will snap to collapsed or expanded based which is closest. How should I disable this snap functionality?

Answer (score 6):

I will present a way to achievie such functionality for a `View` extending `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

**Expanding:**

First of all overrive `onResume`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    addGlobaLayoutListener(getView());
}

private void addGlobaLayoutListener(final View view) {
    view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            setPeekHeight(v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        }
    });
}

public void setPeekHeight(int peekHeight) {
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = getBottomSheetBehaviour();
    if (behavior == null) {
        return;
    }
    behavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeight);
}
```

What the code above is supposed to do is just setting the `BottomSheet` `peekHeight` to the heigth of the view. The key here is the function `getBottomSheetBehaviour()`. The implementation is below:

```
private BottomSheetBehavior getBottomSheetBehaviour() {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) getView().getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        return (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This just check if the parent of `View` has 'CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams' set. If yes, sets appropriate [`BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback.html) (which is needed in the next part), and more importantly returns the `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`, which is supposed to be `BottomSheetBehavior`.

**Collapsing:**

Here a [`BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback.onSlide (View bottomSheet, float slideOffset)``](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback.html#onSlide(android.view.View, float)) is just exactly what is needed. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback.html#onSlide(android.view.View, float)):

> Offset increases as this bottom sheet is moving upward. From 0 to 1 the sheet is between collapsed and expanded states and from -1 to 0 it is between hidden and collapsed states.

This means, that just checking the second parameter is needed for collapse detection:

define `BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback` in the same class:

```
private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        if (slideOffset < 0) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }
};
```