# How can I implement BottomSheetDialogFragment with fixed height

Tags: android, behavior, bottom-sheet

I need to implement `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and face with the problem.
I need that my `BottomSheetDialogFragment` has fixed height. Does anyone has an idea how to do it?

Here is my **xml** of fragment content

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_sheet_height"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drag_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ok_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the `setupDialog()` I am doing this:

```
@Override
public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_content_view, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams());
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(bottomSheetCallback);
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setPeekHeight(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottom_sheet_height));
    }

    initRecyclerView(contentView);
}
```

And behavior is quite common:

```
private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback bottomSheetCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
    }
};
```

---

**UPD:** Solved by set the fixed height to RecyclerView. Does anyone know the better approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can directly give the fix height by Creating it style.

in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper</item>
</style>

<style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">500dp</item>
</style>
```

**Update :**

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomSheetDialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet);
dialog.show();
```

**Or Second Approch :**

```
 CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();

    if( behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior ) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setPeekHeight(300);
    }
```

Comment: How can I use this styles?

Comment: Yea, I see. But unfortunately it's not worked for me. I think the problem is in the RecyclerView it seems like it force to resize parent layout even if it has fixed height

Comment: @VladislavSazanovich  It is same as i suggest you can set Height of `recylcerView` and I am telling you set the `BottomSheet` `Height` in `Style`. but I don't why it not working in you case..

Comment: @VladislavSazanovich used this way `((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setPeekHeight(300);`

Comment: I am also don't know my this is not working)
But thank for your answer.

Comment: Any update on any solution?
@ironman setting peekheight shows the initial dialog nicely but it's still draggable to full height.
btw I know about the STATE_DRAGGING  and the hack solution to set it as expanded, which is not working.
I'm looking for a bottomsheet that stays at a fixed height.

Answer (score 4):

If the `RecyclerView` content is filled inside `initRecyclerView(contentView);` then when showing `BottomSheet` it's height is well known. To set the height of `BottomSheet` dynamically and to wrap the content then add global layout listener inside `onResume` function of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    addGlobaLayoutListener(getView());
}

private void addGlobaLayoutListener(final View view) {
    view.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            setPeekHeight(v.getMeasuredHeight());
            v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        }
    });
}

public void setPeekHeight(int peekHeight) {
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = getBottomSheetBehaviour();
    if (behavior == null) {
        return;
    }
    behavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeight);
}

private BottomSheetBehavior getBottomSheetBehaviour() {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) getView().getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = layoutParams.getBehavior();
    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior) {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
        return (BottomSheetBehavior) behavior;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I really don't like the idea of removing OnLayoutChangeListener. This can lead to the future problems.

Comment: It is used only to get  once the real height of BottomSheet during initialisation. Then is it removed to free resources. If you would add it and wouldn't remove it, every time the `BottomSheet` is shown, a new `OnLayoutChangeListener` would have been attached. Quickly you would run out of resources (memory).

Comment: @R.Zagórski any ways to completely remove dragdown of BottomSheetDialogFragment ??  while using recyclerview ?? https://github.com/rubensousa/BottomSheetExample/issues/3

Comment: You mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757240/android-bottomsheetbehavior-how-to-disable-snap ?

Comment: what is `mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback` here?

Answer (score 2):

Try following code

[image]

1. Create layout xml file for bottomsheet dialog fragment

**layout_bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/ll_bottomSheetFrag_userProf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_icon_nav_d"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/main_white"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
            android:id="@+id/iv_bottomSheetFrag_userPic">
        </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>


        <!-- name & email -->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_bottomSheetFrag_userName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center|start"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_weight="9"
                    android:theme="@style/styleFontMediumText"
                    android:text="@string/user_name"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_bottomSheetFrag_closeDialog"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
                    />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>



            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_bottomSheetFrag_userEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:theme="@style/styleFontRegularText"
                android:textColor="@color/primaryLightColor"
                android:text="@string/user_email" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>



    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_bottomSheetFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_drawer_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_drawer_item_color_state"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_sheet" />


</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

2. Create class for bottom sheet fragment that should extends BottomSheetDialogFragment

**BottomSheetFragment.java**

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment{
@BindView(R.id.iv_bottomSheetFrag_closeDialog) AppCompatImageView iv_closeDialog;
@BindView(R.id.nav_view_bottomSheetFrag_salesPerson) NavigationView nav_view;


private Context context;

//public constructor
public BottomSheetFragment() {

}

//create custom theme for your bottom sheet modal 
@Override
public int getTheme() {
    //return super.getTheme();
    return R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme;
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    return new BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), getTheme());  //set your created theme here

}


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public void setupDialog(@NonNull Dialog dialog, int style)
{
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style);

    View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment, null);
    context = contentView.getContext();
    ButterKnife.bind(this, contentView);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    //tv_title.setText(getString(R.string.app_name)); R.style.AppBottomSheetDialogTheme

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int maxHeight = (int) (height*0.44); //custom height of bottom sheet

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
    ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setPeekHeight(maxHeight);  //changed default peek height of bottom sheet

    if (behavior != null && behavior instanceof BottomSheetBehavior)
    {
        ((BottomSheetBehavior) behavior).setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState)
            {
                String state = "";
                switch (newState)
                {
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING: {
                        //imgBtnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        iv_closeDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        state = "DRAGGING";
                        break;
                    }
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING: {
                        // imgBtnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        iv_closeDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        state = "SETTLING";
                        break;
                    }
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED: {
                        // imgBtnClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        iv_closeDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        state = "EXPANDED";
                        break;
                    }
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED: {
                        //imgBtnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        iv_closeDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        state = "COLLAPSED";
                        break;
                    }
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN: {
                        // imgBtnClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        iv_closeDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        dismiss();
                        state = "HIDDEN";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Log.i("BottomSheetFrag", "onStateChanged: "+ state);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
    }


    //close dialog
    iv_closeDialog.setOnClickListener(view -> dismiss());

}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
}}
```

3. Add these lines in your styles.xml.
   **styles.xml**

```html
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
    </style>
```

4. Rounded shaped drawable for your bottom sheet. Add this file in your drawables folder.

**rounded_dialog.xml**

```html
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>

</shape>
```

5. Finally in your activity call this dialog fragment as follows. Here i have called fragment onClick of bottomNavigationView item onClick listener.

```js
  private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = item ->


{
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bNav_menu:
                BottomSheetFragment bf = new BottomSheetFragment();
                bf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bf.getTag());
                //bf.setArguments(bundle);
                return true;
           
        }
    };
```