# RecyclerView height changes when filtering the list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `BottomSheetFragment` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/BottomSheet"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_text_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            app:boxBackgroundMode="filled"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
            app:endIconMode="custom"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="16dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="16dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="16dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="16dp"
            app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/primary" >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Whenever I filter the list the `BottomSheetFragment` shrinks to a smaller height because of the `RecyclerView`. How can I keep the list full height?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266244/how-can-i-implement-bottomsheetdialogfragment-with-fixed-height

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wonders how I solved the problem. I managed to add at the end of the linear layout a simple empty view with the height and width to match parent.